# ASP.NET Process Start

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, process, iis-express

I made new project (ASP.NET MVC Web Application) using Visual Studio Web 2013 Express Edition. Loading index page, redirects and everything works fine, except that in some part of my code I need to create Process and execute it, wait for it to finish, parse output of that external application and show that output to the user. However I get nothing. While debugging the code line by line:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = Tool;
info.Arguments = filename + " " + avArray;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Process exits immediately, someone would say it is pretty fast program, but application needs at least 5 seconds (sometimes 20 seconds) to complete.
What I think is happening is that process is not created in the first place, as my IIS settings or whatever other settings are not allowing me to run this EXE. What do I do to change this?

Comment: Does the external application run correctly? I mean.. Do you pass the correct path of the application?

Comment: Yes the path is OK and no exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Try the code I write in the answer.

Comment: damn.. Well.. The process you want to run is executed on client side or server side?

Comment: Have a look at [How to run Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to this for the past 2 weeks, I've read probably every post about it, and tried every solution suggested. I am choosing to write on this post since it is the most recent.

First of all, I am using VS2013, testing on IIS Express, and then on IIS 8.5., the webpages version is 3, and the target framework 4.5. And I am assuming that (as with my case) the goal is to launch the process on the server.

What I learned:

1. Using IIS Express should allow you to run the process without problems. You can try to allow it to launch the window, or start your process through the shell just to be sure that it is actually launching (a shell window should popup and close). If this happens, verify that you are giving the correct path to to your program, etc. So far so good.
2. Going into the IIS 8.5 is a totally different matter. Theoretically, the bad way of doing it should be preatty straight-forward: you create an app-pool for that server, give it a high privileged account (local system or network system, for instance); go to AdministrativeTools->Services->IIS, LogOn tab, and allow interaction with the desktop. You should be able to do the same as in IISExpress, but in my case is just the same as with a low privilege account.
3. I actually started by trying just to use impersonation, but also was not able to launch the process with IIS8.5. **EDIT:** I retried this again today, and the api won't even run if I enable impersonation.

I've spent more time than I would like with this, any input on why I can't get this to work properly with IIS8.5 (@clzola: IIS Express should do the job) is very welcome.

Comment: I have actually managed to solve this by adding high privileged account to my app-pool .net 4.0. I have successfully configured two machines with IIS8.5 installed, to run processes..